# Can't get texts out of a few dd tags that started after a certain dt tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get text out of `dd` tags located between the two `dt` tags. I'm interested in the text within `dd` tags that started after `dt` tag, which contains `Bransje`, until the next `dt` tag.

The next `dt` tag contains `Stillingsfunksjon`, which may not always be the case. Given that the next `dt` tag may contain anything.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <section class="panel">
        <dl class="definition-list definition-list--inline">
            <dt>Sektor</dt>
                <dd>Privat</dd>
            <dt>Sted</dt>
                <dd>Bratsbergveien 5, 7037 Trondheim</dd>
            <dt>Bransje</dt>
                <dd>Industri og produksjon,</dd>
                <dd>Maritim og offshore,</dd>
                <dd>Olje og gass</dd>
            <dt>Stillingsfunksjon</dt>
                <dd>Ingeniør</dd>
        </dl>
    </section>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
for i in soup.select("dt:-soup-contains('Bransje') ~ dd"):
    print(i.text)
```

Current output:

```
Industri og produksjon,
Maritim og offshore,
Olje og gass
Ingeniør
```

Expected output:

```
Industri og produksjon,
Maritim og offshore,
Olje og gass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get there:

```
for i in soup.select("dt:-soup-contains('Bransje') ~ *"):
    if i.name=="dt":
        break
    else:
        print(i.text)
```

Output should be your expected output.